# NoSuchElementException in nextInt() no matter what I do to the code

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

```
public class MinimumElement {

public void readIntegers(int userCount) {
    int count = userCount;
    int intArray[] = new int[count];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++) {
        int number;
        System.out.println("Please input number ");
        number = scan.nextInt();
        intArray[i] = number;
    }
    scan.close();
}

public static void main(String[] Args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of elements required for array");
    int userInput = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
    MinimumElement min = new MinimumElement();
    min.readIntegers(userInput);

}

}
```

Have tried `hasNextInt` and `hasNextLine` with `if` conditions as well. They are always returning result value as `false`.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: Ouput of the code:
    =================
    
    
    >>please enter the number of elements required for array
    3
    >>Please input number 
    >>Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException 
     >>at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
     >>at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
     >>at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
     >>at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
     >>at MinimumElement.readIntegers(MinimumElement.java:14)
     >>at MinimumElement.main(MinimumElement.java:270)

Comment: Cannot reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I believe I might've found a solution to your problem. The issue lies within the way you attempt to read from `System.in`: you allocate two instances of `Scanner` tied to the same `System.in` input stream.

```
int intArray[] = new int[count];
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And over there:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the number of elements required for array");
```

This is going to cause problems. Therefore, create a global instance of `Scanner` like shown in the example below instead.

```
public class MinimumElement {

    private static Scanner SCANNER;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of elements required for array");
        try {
            int userInput = SCANNER.nextInt();
            SCANNER.nextLine();
            MinimumElement min = new MinimumElement();
            min.readIntegers(userInput);
        } finally {
            SCANNER.close();
        }
    }

    public void readIntegers(int userCount) {
        int[] intArray = new int[userCount];
        for (int i = 0; i <= userCount - 1; i++) {
            int number;
            System.out.println("Please input number ");
            number = SCANNER.nextInt();
            intArray[i] = number;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you must take care not to interact with the `Scanner` after invoking its `close()` method, as that will result in erroneous behaviour as well.